# ShowleaderboardsUI(); not working

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I' ve been working for a while on connecting my app with google play services and I ve got a problem that my user connects to the application, but after that I made a button with "ShowleaderboardsUI ();" and after clicking that nothing happens. I've added my email to tester group.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using GooglePlayGames;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

public class AchievmentManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    private bool IsConnectedToGoogleServices;

   void Start()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
        IsConnectedToGoogleServices = false;
        ConnectToGoogleServices();
    }

 public bool ConnectToGoogleServices()
    {
        if (!IsConnectedToGoogleServices)
        {
            {
                Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
                    {
                        IsConnectedToGoogleServices = success;
                    });
            }
        }
        return IsConnectedToGoogleServices;
    }

    public void ToLeaderboard()
    {
        if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
        {
            Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Unable to connect google play services");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try adding this to your android mainfest:

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

You can create custom mainfest in Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidMainfest.xml